# When importing .fbx files into unreal engine, all of the textures just become a white base color. How can I fix this?

Tags: import, textures, game-engine, fbx, unreal-engine5

This is how the files look look like in the content browser:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJugN.png

This is how the textures look like in the material graph:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IksN.png

I have followed several tutorials and never get the same results as them (i.e. object imported with textures.)
I have the same issue with all file formats which unreal engine supports.
All the objects I tried were free 3D I downloaded online.
Does anyone have a solution to this?